# Multiple login pages with Spring Security and Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot application which will be used by two different groups of people, with different views and functionality.

I want to have two different login pages for them at `/admin/login` and `/company/login`.

I have created two WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter static classes in my security config class and each has an @Order annotation. One with @Order(1) and another with @Order(2) as shown below.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AdminUserDetailService adminUserDetailService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(AdminUserDetailService adminUserDetailService) {
        this.adminUserDetailService = adminUserDetailService;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(adminUserDetailService);
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class AdminConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        public AdminConfigurationAdapter() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/admin/login").hasRole("Admin")
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/admin/login")
                    .permitAll(true)
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/admin/logout")
                    .permitAll();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class CompanyConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        public CompanyConfigurationAdapter() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/company/login").hasRole("Company Admin")
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/company/login")
                    .permitAll(true)
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/company/logout")//our new logout success url, we are not replacing other defaults.
                    .permitAll();//allow all as it will be accessed when user is not logged in anymore
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/scripts/**", "/img/**", "/vendor/**", "/api/user/**");
    }

}
```

My problem now is Spring Security is always taking to `/company/login` even if I enter `/admin/login` in the URL. I am not sure what is wrong with my configuration.

Comment: they both configure the same, the global config... Start with `http.antMatchers("/company/**")` to configure for a specific (nested) URL. Currently everything is for the default.

Answer (score 1):

As per official guide [multiple-httpsecurity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity), define your first configuration like this..you have to define base path otherwise it will always call first.

```
 @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class CompanyConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/company/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/company/login").hasRole("Company Admin")
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/company/login")
                    .permitAll(true)
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/company/logout")//our new logout success url, we are not replacing other defaults.
                    .permitAll();//allow all as it will be accessed when user is not logged in anymore
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same with use of @order annotation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AllConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    MyUserDeatailService myuserDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public static BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {

        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(4);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authProvider() {

        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        provider.setUserDetailsService(myuserDetailsService);

        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public static AuthenticationFailureHandler customAuthenticationFailureHandler() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class AdminSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.requestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/admin/**"))
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
            .and().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/admin/adminlogin").permitAll().usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password").defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/AdminDashBoard")
            .failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler()).and().logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/home").and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class UserSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.requestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/user/**"))
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')").and().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/user/userlogin").permitAll().usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password").defaultSuccessUrl("/user/UserDashBoard")
            .failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler()).and().logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/").and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
        }

    }
}
```